# Filling NA with the information of another column

Tags: r

```
tablenew <- table %>%
  mutate (i_a_i = case_when (
    INaam != 'NA' ~ INaam[],
    INaam == 'NA' ~ ANaam[],
    ANaam  == 'NA' & INaam == 'NA' ~ InNaam[]
    ))
```

what i basically want if INaam has missing data it will use the name in column Anaam and if both of these are missing NA then use InNaam. It doesn't really does completely what I want. Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `NA` values using `is.na`, also I think this can be reduced to only two conditions

```
library(dplyr)
table %>%
   mutate(i_a_i = case_when(
                     is.na(INaam) ~ Anaam,
                     TRUE ~ INaam))
```

If there is missing value in `INaam` you want to use `Anaam` value and for non-missing value use `INaam`.

Or just use `ifelse`

```
table$i_a_i <- with(table, ifelse(is.na(INaam), Anaam, INaam))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you are right about the reduction! Need to add more columns if the second one was empty as well, but i managed so great!!!!